# Как узнать по какому url была загружена текущая страница?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Смысл вопроса в том, что после загрузки страницы нужно проверить ее url и если урл, например, выглядит так:

```
http://example.com/index.html#sometab
```

то сделать активной вкладку с `id="sometab"`. А если в url не содержится никаких "якорей", то не делать ничего.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(/#sometab/.test(location.href))
{
    //какие-то действия
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так: (просто конструкция по-прозрачнее получается)

```
if (location.hash && location.hash == "#sometab") {
  // действия
}
```